# Ionic react component rendering repeated

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am unable to get order id at order details page because react component rendering multiple times. I have tried with below solutions but it's not work

https://codesandbox.io/s/solution-re-rendering-problem-tabs-6qskh?file=/src/pages/Tab1/Tab1.tsx

How can I stop rendering multiple times

error page

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVDe6.png)

order.tsx

```
import {
  IonButton,
  IonCol,
  IonContent,
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonText,
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Orders.css";
import axios from "axios";

export const Orders: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("order page");

  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    getOrders().then((data) => {
      if (isMounted) {
        setOrders(data.orderList.data);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  const getOrders = async () => {
    return axios({
      url: "http://example.com/api/orders",
      method: "get",
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    });
  };

  return (
    <IonContent>
      <div className="ion-padding">
        <h1>Orders</h1>
      </div>

      <IonList color="primary">
        {orders.map((order) => {
          return (
            <IonItem key={order.order_number}>
              {order.order_number}
              <IonButton
                routerLink={`/orderdetails/${order.order_code}`}
                color="primary"
                slot="end"
              >
                View
              </IonButton>
            </IonItem>
          );
        })}
      </IonList>
    </IonContent>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Orders);
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  IonApp,
  IonIcon,
  IonLabel,
  IonRouterOutlet,
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  IonTabs,
  IonSplitPane,
  useIonRouter,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router";
import { images, ellipse, square, triangle } from "ionicons/icons";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import MainTabs from "./MainTabs";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import { userContext } from "./userContext";
import Orders from "./pages/Orders";
import OrderDetails from "./pages/OrderDetails";
import { Plugins, Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core";

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import "@ionic/react/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import "@ionic/react/css/normalize.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/structure.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/typography.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import "@ionic/react/css/padding.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/display.css";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { authValues, setAuthValues } = React.useContext(userContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Capacitor.isNative) {
      Plugins.App.addListener("backButton", (e) => {
        if (
          window.location.pathname === "/tab1" ||
          window.location.pathname === "/login"
        ) {
          // Show A Confirm Box For User to exit app or not
          //let ans = window.confirm("Are you sure");
          //if (ans) {
          Plugins.App.exitApp();
          //}
        }
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <IonApp>
      {authValues.authenticated ? (
        <IonReactRouter>
          <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
            <Menu />
            <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
              <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} exact />
              <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} exact />
              <Route path="/orderdetails/:order_id" component={OrderDetails} exact />
              <MainTabs />
            </IonRouterOutlet>
          </IonSplitPane>
        </IonReactRouter>
      ) : (
        <IonReactRouter>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/login" exact />
        </IonReactRouter>
      )}
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

order detail page

```
import {
  IonButton,
  IonCol,
  IonContent,
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonText,
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,  
  IonFab, 
  IonFabButton, 
  IonIcon
} from "@ionic/react"
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./OrderDetails.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL;

export const OrderDetails: React.FC = () => {

  let { order_id } = useParams();

  console.log(order_id);

  console.log("order detail page");

  const [order, setOrder] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true
    getOrderDetails().then( data => {
      if (isMounted) {
        setOrder(data.orderDetails)
      }
    })
    return () => { isMounted = false }
  }, []);

  const getOrderDetails = async () => {
    return axios({
      url: 'http://example.com/api/order-details/10623',
      method: "get",
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    });
  };

  return (
    <IonContent>
      <div className="ion-padding">
        <h1>Order Details</h1>
      </div>

      <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>
            Order No.: {order.order_number}
          </IonLabel>
        </IonItem>

    </IonContent>
  )
}

export default React.memo(OrderDetails);
```

Comment: The code in the linked sandbox doesn't seem to match that which you included in your snippets. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and ***Reproducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: Added missing page

Comment: Sandbox code still isn't a match, but you've a typo. Path is `path="/orderdetails/:id"` but you try to access *some* `order_id` param (`let { order_id } = useParams();`). Access the correct route match param, i.e. `let { id } = useParams();`. Voting to close. **Side note:** don't console log in the body of functional components, use a `useEffect` hook to truly log any values when the component renders to the DOM.

Comment: I have updated id to order_id but it's still not get order_id at order details page. It return undefined as same error screen-shot. checked within useEffect but same issue. Also why it rendering multiple times?

Comment: Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we may live debug in? Replace the current one in your question as that appears to be completely unrelated code. About the "multiple rerenders", see my comment about console logging as an unintentional side-effect.